# How to get the TEAM API Key for microsoft appcenter

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-test-cloud, visual-studio-app-center

I am using cake script to deploy xamarin ui scipts on the test cloud, for this I would need the API key of the team in app center I am running my scripts against. I was able to find those keys in xamarin test cloud but after they moved to microsoft appcenter, I am not able to find the team's api key on Microsoft appcenter which is needed to run the test scripts.

> https://github.com/Redth/Cake.Xamarin/blob/master/src/Cake.Xamarin/TestCloudRunner.cs
>   https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Xamarin/MDToolSettings/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin Test Cloud had Team Key. Microsoft appcenter doesn't have any team key. Appcenter does had API tokens under 
user settings ->account settings->API tokens